# macOS: tccd often crashes and locks up the system for a minute; how to diagnose?

Tags: macos, permission, performance

I am using macOS 10.14.6. After certain actions, such as starting the screensaver and other "innocent" things, the system locks up for about a minute. The mouse pointer can be moved, but nothing else reacts or moves on screen. I just have to wait it out.

Looking at the console, I can see six `.crash` files for `tccd`, with timestamps about 10 seconds apart, after each such event. The contents are like this:

```
Process:               tccd [11633]
Path:                  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/Versions/A/Resources/tccd
Identifier:            tccd
Version:               221.260.3

...

Crashed Thread:        1  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
dyld3 mode
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSFileManager fileSystemRepresentationWithPath:]: nil or empty path argument'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called
```

To trigger the problem, it is sufficient to open the Desktop & Screensaver preferences, which shows a preview of the screensaver.

*UPDATE: Trying to choose the picture source for screensavers causes a several minutes long hang. It seems that the problem is with the screensaver trying to access data on disk. The picture source has always been set to the default though.*

I have now completely disabled the screensaver to try to avoid this problem. But unfortunately, it is sometimes (non-reproducibly) triggered by other actions as well, typically either using dictionary lookup (with "force-click") or using quicklook in a file-chooser dialog. Of course, it always happens when I'm in a hurry and trying to get work done ...

---

What can I do to find the root cause of the problem, and resolve it?

This problem has persisted for several months now and I had no luck in diagnosing it, other than discovering the relationship to `tccd`, which is responsible for controlling the access of programs to "sensitive" user data.

---

**UPDATE:** The same problem is reported [here](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/security-update-2020-004.2246032/page-2?post=28831945#post-28831945) and claimed to be related to security update 2020-004.

---

What I tried so far:

- Reset the TCC database using `tccutil reset All`.
- [Here](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/security-update-2020-004.2246032/page-3?post=28970745#post-28970745) is it claimed that uninstalling Dropbox helped. I tried this and it made no difference.

Comment: The first link in your post mentions an OS reinstall, might be worth trying

Comment: @nohillside Thanks for the comment! More accurately, he said that the purpose of the re-install was to get rid of security update 2020-004. Thus, the choice would be between having a security update that fixes zero-days or avoiding the UI hangs. At the moment I am not really willing to take the risk of a re-install as I cannot afford to be without a usable machine even for one day. If nothing better comes up, I might try the reinstall at a more relaxed time (work-wise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is fixed by Security Update 2020-007. Instead of crashing, TCCD now prints the following warning into system log:

TCC         From PID[xxxx]: realPath of reponsible path () fails: Receiver must not be nil or contain the empty string.

Comment: I confirm that after installing Security Update 2020-007 on my Mojave machine, I no longer see these hangs.